# Difference between denial and denying?

Tags: word-choice

> There is no **denial** that Richard was a great human being.

Is it a right use of denial?

Comment: It's usually **denying** but this question shows no research effort and would be better on ELL.

Comment: It is an idiomatic expression: ***there's no denying*** https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/there-s-no-denying

Comment: "There is no denial" would only be correct if you actually took a poll, and no one denied it.

Comment: If you mean no one could ever say the guy was not great, then "there's no denying" it, as comments have shown.

Answer (score 0):

> [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/denial)
> *denial*, noun
> a statement that something is not true or does not exist
> *The CEO issued a denial of the report that she is about to resign.*

Your sentence lacks context but may confidently be imagined to refer to the opinion of some or many people about Richard. Considering those people, there was no denial of Richard's greatness. To express it otherwise: they made no denial of it; they expressed no denial; none of them denied it. As such, the sentence is clear, unambiguous and correct.

An alternative and more conventional expression would be "There was no denying that Richard was a great human being". However, the existence of a conventional form does not invalidate other forms and your sentence remains correct.